# HTML button to open URL in a new window

Tags: javascript, c#, html, html-email

I'm populating an email template and I'm having some issues with the button onclick event.

What I am trying to achieve is when clicking on the button it should open a URL in a new window rather than a new tab.

Currently when the email gets sent it is losing the onclick event functionality. Any recommendations on how can I achieve this?

I have also tried creating the button in the html template rather than replacing the tags as code below, but still run into the same issue.

HTML Code:

```
    <p>
        Hi,
    </p>
    <p>
        A [JobType], to start on [JobStartDate]
        <br />
        Click here to view the job: [JobUrl]
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Job Details:</b>
        <br />
        - Reference: [JobReferenceNumber]
        <br />
        - Checklist: [AnswerEvaluationName]
        <br />
        - Created by: [JobCreator]
        <br />
    </p>
    <p>
        Kind regards<br />
    </p>
    <p class="auto-style6">
        Please do not reply to this system generated email
    </p>
</body>
```

```
public void CreateEmailNotificationForNewJob()
{
   // Populate the Email Template
   string EmailRecipientTestingNotes = "";
   string EmailSubject = "";
   string EmailTemplate = EmailSender.LoadEmailTemplate("EmailNewJob.html");
   string EmailTo = "";
   string TestButton = ("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.open('https://www.google.com/','mywin','width=500,height=500');\" >");

   EmailSubject = "Job/task ";
   EmailTemplate = EmailTemplate.Replace("[JobReferenceNumber]", "Reference");
   EmailTemplate = EmailTemplate.Replace("[AnswerEvaluationName]", "Daily Update");
   EmailTemplate = EmailTemplate.Replace("[JobStartDate]", "Today");
   EmailTemplate = EmailTemplate.Replace("[JobType]", "1");
   EmailTemplate = EmailTemplate.Replace("[CompanySiteName]", "");
   EmailTemplate = EmailTemplate.Replace("[SiteName]", "");
   EmailTemplate = EmailTemplate.Replace("[JobUrl]", TestButton);

   EmailTo = "test@test.co.za";

   try
   {
      // Send email code
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // Add handling
   }
}
```

Comment: Not really a C# question but rather HTML; just make the button an anchor (<a> tag) with the target attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 3):

Most email clients don't allow execution of JavaScript like a browser would (usually this is for security reasons).

But if you want to create a link to a URL to display in the email, you can just use a hyperlink instead of a button. (You can of course always use CSS to make it *look* like a button, if you wish.)

```
string TestButton = ("<a href='https://www.google.com/'>Click here</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Email clients won't accept JavaScript.
The best you can do is to use a standard link with the target attribute set to _blank:

```
string TestButton = ("<a href='www.blah.com' target='_blank'>link text</a>");
```

Having said that, most email clients will open in a new/blank tab anyway. However, this is helpful still for those who use click "view this email in your browser" (on Outlook desktop, for example, this is generated automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hyperlink instead of a button because email clients won't accept JavaScript. 
Of course you can use css to make it looks like a button.

Button:

```
string TestButton = ("<a class='button' href='https://www.google.com/'>Click here</a>");
```

Css:

```
.button {
font: bold 11px Arial;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
color: #333333;
padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-right: 1px solid #333333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Some email clients will not read CSS in the head of the document. Its best to inline the code for global support.

Comment: Was simply trying to say your answer is half complete. Your code will be a link in Outlook and not a button. Email doesn't have support like a browser does.